# Accessing $rootScope content in factory return undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, factory

I am puzzled.

First, i observe this in Ionic 1+ (but i assume this is probably related to AngularJS)

I created a factory, with the $rootScope injected.

In my app.js, i have assigned a variable, says

```
 var app = angular.module('my-module',
     app.run(['$rootScope', ...

         $rootScope.strUrl = 'http://localhost:30000'
```

Then i need to use this variable inside the factory. Precisely, access it just after it is loaded.

```
 angular.module('my-module')
        .factory('myFactory', ['$rootScope', ...]);
 function myFactory($rootScope, ...){
     var objUrl = {
                     baseUrl: $rootScope.strUrl,
                     ....
     }
 }
```

What puzzles me is that, when i access $rootScope.strUrl inside the factory, it returns undefined. However, just one line before that, i am able to `console.log($rootScope.strUrl)` which returns exactly the string i want.

Is it not possible to access the $rootScope content inside the factory?

Comment: If you have solved your issue please delete the question.  If not please reword your question because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: how should this question be reworded? It actually shows what i observed.

Comment: If we are going to help we need to understand where you set `rootScope.strUrl = 'http://localhost:30000'` . Saying it's in `app.js` doesn't help us at all.

Comment: alright. question edited. thx for reminder.

Comment: What module is `app` above?

Comment: Just Added.... should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... guess i know what went wrong. It is the problem of sequence.

angularjs would go through my factory first before running app.run(['$rootScope',...]

Yet, the console.log is kind of misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to set a "config" you have two better options.  The easiest is to use a `constant`, a `value` if your paranoid, and a `provider` if you want a jackhammer.  A an example of how to use a constant, which is accessible for both providers and services is below.  Providers are more complex, but if you use one you can set / configure it using the `config` step of the app.

```
 var app = angular.module('my-module', []);

 app.constant('settings', {strUrl : 'http://localhost:30000'});

 app.factory('myFactory', myFactory);
 function myFactory(settings){
      var objUrl = {
                 baseUrl: $settings.strUrl,
                 ....

      }
 }
```

See the [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider) docs for a more detailed explination.

---

As for your "issue" depending on what you access in your run, and what you return from your myFactory you could run into issues.  If your `.run` method pulls in a dependency that is dependent on myFactory then the `digest` will not have had time to complete by the time it injects your myFactory.  I don't think the way you have it is ideal and in the past i have used `constants` and `providers` to configure my app.   We have an open source library that does what you are trying to do for you.  But the documentation is pretty lacking ;)

https://bitbucket.org/unboxedtech/angular.core/src/e2b1b8dd9457de7b334655f09410da1a78fb55c8/app/src/urls/?at=master

Basically you define a settings object:

```
app.constant('settings', {
    base: 'http://localhost:30000/'
});
```

Add our `UrlInterceptor` interceptor during the run step.

And it allows for you to do things like:

```
$http('~/someresource') 
// which translates to http://localhost:3000/someresource


$http('~(api)/someendpoint') 
// which translates to http://localhost:3000/api/someendpoint
```

It also works with templates and any other `http` dependent service.